# Problem downloading MMLSpark library as a Maven dependency

Tags: java, maven, jar

I am completely new to working with maven. I´m trying to download a jar file from microsofts MMLSPARK library using the command of the screenshot:

[image]

I´m getting this error ... No clue what's the problem.

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:get (default-cli) on project standalone-pom: Couldn't download artifact: Missing:
[ERROR] ----------
[ERROR] 1) com.microsoft.ml.spark:mmlspark_2.11:jar:1.0.0-rc1
[ERROR]
[ERROR]   Try downloading the file manually from the project website.
[ERROR]
[ERROR]   Then, install it using the command:
[ERROR]       mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=com.microsoft.ml.spark -DartifactId=mmlspark_2.11 -Dversion=1.0.0-rc1 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file
[ERROR]
[ERROR]   Alternatively, if you host your own repository you can deploy the file there:
[ERROR]       mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=com.microsoft.ml.spark -DartifactId=mmlspark_2.11 -Dversion=1.0.0-rc1 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file -Durl=[url] -DrepositoryId=[id]
[ERROR]
[ERROR]   Path to dependency:
[ERROR]         1) org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-downloader-plugin:jar:1.0
[ERROR]         2) com.microsoft.ml.spark:mmlspark_2.11:jar:1.0.0-rc1
[ERROR]
[ERROR] ----------
[ERROR] 1 required artifact is missing.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] for artifact:
[ERROR]   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-downloader-plugin:jar:1.0
[ERROR]
[ERROR] from the specified remote repositories:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you have a weird configuration of maven, the command of the screenshot works! I just executed it. The result is getting a jar, called mmlspark_2.11-1.0.0-rc1.jar in the current working directory.

Also, make sure that you put this exactly:

```
mvn dependency:get -DremoteRepositories="https://mmlspark.azureedge.net/maven" -Dartifact="com.microsoft.ml.spark:mmlspark_2.11:1.0.0-rc1" -Ddest=.
```

(Copy&Paste it!)

If you continue getting problems, add the -X flag (debug mode) to the command, it will print more information of what is going on under the hood ...

Comment: Hi. The issue is that the screen shot was from the github issue where someone was able to successfully run the commands. I was not able to. In that github issue, another user had the same error as I did.